# IntelliJ's Tomcat Server plugin does not set proper classpath for multi-module projects

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to use IntelliJ to deploy my multi-module application directly to a local Tomcat server (i.e. a Tomcat v7.0 running on my laptop).

The classes created in child-modules are each packaged up as a .jar file. These .jars are included in the application's lib folder, i.e. after deployment and "exploding" of the .war file by Tomcat the classes of the main module sit in

`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\<application-name>\WEB-INF\classes`

while all libraries (i.e. all dependencies as well as all the child-modules' jars) are deployed to

`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\<application-name>\WEB-INF\lib`.

When I then run that application from within the IDE (i.e. Services --> Right-click on config --> run) the application starts but then stalls with a class not found exception. As turned out the child-modules' jars are not on the classpath.

I got things running by adding

`-cp "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\zhquest_web_war\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\zhquest_web_war\WEB-INF\lib"`

to the "VM options"-field in the run configuration.

But it still beats me: why is IntelliJ not automatically adding the `lib` folder to Tomcat's classpath?

Under "Project structure..." I see all those sub-modules being defined in the project. Also all Maven dependencies are listed there. I would have expected that IntelliJ either adds all folders that contain generated classes, i.e. each modules' `...\target\classes` directory to the classpath or that it adds the generated .jars as libraries to the classpath and thus would not force me to fiddle with the application's classpath manually.

What am I missing in the configuration of my project?

Hope I could make myself clear...

(I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Ultimate Edition) / Build #IU-222.4345.14